# I am trying to perform mathematical operations to inputed data in elixir but its throwing an arithmetic error

Tags: elixir

I am new to elixir, I am trying to perform mathematical operations on received data in this case, calculate the tithe of salary got from the user and its throwing this error:

```elixir
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    m.ex:11: M.calc/0*
```

here is my code

```elixir
def calc do
  salary = IO.gets("What is your salary?") |> String.trim
  x = salary
  IO.puts "Your tithe this month is: #{(x * 0.01)}"
end
```

Comment: You should parse the value as a number in order to use it in a mathematical operation

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is that `IO.gets` will give you binaries (e.g. Strings). One thing you can do to check what you're receiving is using `IO.inspect(salary)`

It should probably produce something like

`"1000\n"`

So, you might need to remove the `\n` and then parse. You can remove by using [`String.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4)

You might also need to remove any special characters included (e.g `$`).

Then, when you have the number itself, you can use [`String.to_integer/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_integer/1) or [`String.to_float/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_float/1) to parse the number depending on if you're expecting an integer or a float value.

A basic working version could be:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def main do   
     calc()
  end

  def calc do
    salary =
      IO.gets("What is your salary?")
      |> String.trim()
      |> String.replace("\n", "")
      |> String.to_integer()

    IO.puts "Your tithe this month is: #{salary * 0.01}"
  end
end
```

Assuming that the numbers will always be integers. But of course, you can add more logic to account for both.

You could also use [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/1) and [`Float.parse`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#parse/1) instead, which might help in removing additional characters, like:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def main do   
     calc()
  end

  def calc do
    {salary, _other_chars} =
      IO.gets("What is your salary?")
      |> Float.parse()

    IO.puts "Your tithe this month is: #{salary * 0.01}"
  end
end
```

It might be a better, more generic function, but it will always produce a float

Comment: Good answer. I was personally surprised that Integer.parse would actually produce useable results. `Integer.parse("1122aaa")` yields `{1122, "aaa"}. I like it.

Comment: Yes, that and `Float.parse` have that useful functionality of parsing an integer or float value if found within the string, so it turns out very useful for parsing user provided values that might have currency symbols or other things that can be stripped, while allowing you to use them if necessary